# What is it - popular riddle

Tags: riddle

This was a really popular riddle a few years ago and I did not find it posted here, so I might as well ask it. What is it?

Who makes it has no need of it
Who uses it is not aware of using it
Who buys it has no use for it

Answer (score 0):

I think it got it

> is it a coffin

Comment: That was fast, did you figure it out this quickly without cheating? :)